# Fake users with fake questions?

Tags: discussion

It seems to me that this site is "infested" by "one-shot" users that ask questions about logic : very trivial, without any ref to textbook or similar, without context, without any interesting issue whatever.

To see what I mean, it is enough to sort questions by "logic" or "fitch" tags and we will finf that many (most ?) of them are submitted by "one shot" users. Here are some recent examples : [today post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67652/tableaux-for-normal-modal-logics), [yesterday post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67644/how-to-prove-a-v-b-a-b-by-natural-deduction) and [yesterday post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67642/how-to-derive-p-q-r-from-p-q-r-in-fitch).

Is it possible that some "real" user of the site proliferates producing "fake users" only for submitting this type of questions ?

Is there any way to detect this phenomenon ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you point towards some examples? It would make an investigation of that issue much easier.

Comment: I'd generally assume that people who come here with their homework questions are often "one-shot" users, and since this site seems to be the place to ask these questions, it doesn't seem odd to me that we see alot of these cases (as GT said in one place, last year it was a disaster).

Comment: @YechiamWeiss I agree that it make sense that people come just for homework questions, but it is strange that it happens so often. Why do so many come here? How do they find this website? It's not that it's so popular. My guess is that some people got their homework questions answered here and shared it with their school friends for the same purpose. It certainly doesn't help that some users here [do their homework for them so readily](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/67646/20618).

Comment: (Which, by the way, should really be discouraged. Maybe we should have a separate discussion on that.)

Comment: @Eliran definitely agree on having that discussion.

Comment: @Eliran StackExchange often is first on google if you search for certain combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the examples given and can assure you that they do not have anything to do with one another or more regular users.

I'm afraid the perceived raise in numbers regarding basic logic questions recently is simply due to the uni terms having had started recently and students taking basic logic lectures heading for help in the wrong place/fashion.

I can only imagine how other sites like math and physics etc. are flooded with freshers' coursework as well right now.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. "... heading for help in the wrong place/fashion" - I'd like to bring up this to a discussion as well. Is Phil.SE the correct place for such questions? I know that [that's what SE says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194693/where-to-ask-question-about-logic), but should it stay that way? The over-flooding of homework-style *logic* (specifically, and almost only in the field of logic) that comes in waves, be it justified or not, begs the discussion imo.

Comment: Ok, thanks. :-)